# Loop through array in Chef Template (ERB)

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, ansible, jinja2, erb

I'm new to `chef` and starting to learn the ropes and want to know if the below is possible and how to achieve it. I'm coming from someone who's been using `ansible` for the past 2 years.

I want to know how to manipulate `.erb` templates

`ansible code` - `varible.yml`

```
apache_vhosts:
  - servername: "{{ enterprise }}.test.io"
    serveralias: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
    documentroot: "/var/www/test/current/web"
    symfony_prod: true
    redirect_https: true
  - servername: "{{ enterprise }}forms.test.io"
    documentroot: "/var/www/test/current/web"
    symfony_form: true
    redirect_https: true
  - servername: "{{ enterprise }}trk.test.io"
    documentroot: "/var/www/test/current/web"
    symfony_track: true
    redirect_https: true
```

`ansible code` - `vhosts.conf.j2` (`jinja template`)

```
{% for vhost in apache_vhosts %}
<VirtualHost *:{{ apache_listen_port_http }}>
  ServerName {{ vhost.servername }}
{% if vhost.redirect_https is defined and vhost.redirect_https == true %}
  Redirect 301 / https://{{ vhost.servername }}/
  {% else %}
  DocumentRoot {{ vhost.documentroot }}
{% if vhost.serveradmin is defined %}
  ServerAdmin {{ vhost.serveradmin }}
{% endif %}

{% if vhost.symfony_dev is defined %}

  DirectoryIndex app_dev.php

  <Directory "{{ vhost.documentroot }}">
    AllowOverride None
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    # Symfony2 rewriting rules
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app_dev.php [L]
  </Directory>
{% elif vhost.symfony_prod is defined %}

  DirectoryIndex app.php

  <Directory "{{ vhost.documentroot }}">
    AllowOverride None
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    # Symfony2 rewriting rules
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
  </Directory>
{% else %}

  <Directory "{{ vhost.documentroot }}">
    AllowOverride All
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

{% endif %}

{% if vhost.extra_parameters is defined %}
  {{ vhost.extra_parameters }}
{% endif %}

{% endif %}

</VirtualHost>

{% endfor %}
```

From the code above, you can see that I'm looping through `apache_vhosts` in the `.yml` file and using the inner objects as I create the template. Is this possible with `.erb` how do I replicate this in a `.rb` attributes file.

Currently I just have the below;

`chef code` - `default.rb`

```
# Apache attributes
default["altostack"]["apache_conf_path"] = "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled"
default["altostack"]["apache_redirect_https"] = false
default["altostack"]["apache_servername"] = "test.test.io"
default["altostack"]["apache_documentroot"] = "/var/www/test/current/web"
default["altostack"]["apache_ssl_crt_dir"] = case node.environment
when '_default'
  default["altostack"]["apache_ssl_crt_dir"] = "/etc/apache2/ssl/"
end
```

Answer (score 4):

To replicate more or less your `ansible` format:

```
# Apache attributes

default["altostack"]["test.test.io"]["apache_conf_path"] = "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled"
default["altostack"]["test.test.io"]["apache_redirect_https"] = false
default["altostack"]["test.test.io"]["apache_documentroot"] = "/var/www/test/current/web"
default["altostack"]["test.test.io"]["apache_ssl_crt_dir"] = case node.environment
when '_default'
   "/etc/apache2/ssl/"
end

#Alternative synteax with hash:

default["altostack"]["test_2.test.io"]= {
  "apache_conf_path" => "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled",
  "apache_redirect_https" => false,
  "apache_documentroot" => "/var/www/test/current/web"
}

# For the case statement, better use the usual approach, easier to maitain IMHO
default["altostack"]["test_2.test.io"]["apache_ssl_crt_dir"] = case node.environment
  when '_default'
     "/etc/apache2/ssl/"
  end
```

In the template file:

```
<% node['altostack'].each do |servername,properties| -%>
  <VirtualHost *:<%= properties['apache_redirect_https'] %>
    ServerName <%= servername %>
    <% if !properties['redirect_https'].nil? and properties['redirect_https'] == true -%>
  Redirect 301 / https://<%= servername %>/
  <% else -%>
  DocumentRoot <%= properties['documentroot'] %>
<% if !properties['serveradmin'].nil? -%>
  ServerAdmin <%= properties['serveradmin'] %>
<% endif -%>
# Rest of template to be translated by yourself :)
```

The template syntax in chef is using erb, it is covered in the [documentation here](https://docs.chef.io/resource_template.html) and it accept plain ruby within the template.

The usual recomendation is to take advantage of community cookbooks, here namely [`apache2`](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/apache2) which has a nice [Usage](https://github.com/svanzoest-cookbooks/apache2/#usage) section in it's readme and a basic example usage of it's [`web_app`](https://github.com/svanzoest-cookbooks/apache2/#web_app) resource.

Comment: thanks for this, I'm avoiding focusing alot on the community cookbooks as I believe they're very overwhelming compare to there equivalent ansible galaxy roles. I'll ofcourse be looking at their patterns and structure. My goal is to understand the syntax and be able to create templates and work with attributes so that when I then start making my own cookbooks I don't run into any surprises.

Comment: @shady I'll highly encourage you to got through http://learn.chef.io in this case ;)

Comment: I believe this is something more to do with knowing `ruby` language and the `erb` engine.. Same way learning `ansible` won't teach you how to use `jinja2` templates rather your knowledge of `python` in addition to the template engine docs

Comment: For the templates, yes, but the chef doc cover the basic usage if looping over attribute hash. Advanced ruby is usually not needed until you write complex providers for chef

Comment: Maybe I'm being to ambitious trying to lift and shift `yaml` to `rb` lol.. I'll need to create hashes of hashes and loop through to achieve that

Comment: Well, yaml, json or ruby hashes are still what a pythonist would call a dictionary IIRC :) That's jsut a matter of syntax at first, the core principles are the same